# How to switch bundle according hostname in symfony2

Tags: symfony

I would like to inherit a bundle to override only some layout parts, with a hostname condition.

My 'FirstBundle' for www.site1.com is ready. I configured main routing in MyApp/config/routing.yml

```
www_site1_com:
  resource: "@FirstBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
  prefix:   /
```

FirstBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml contains my full routing. I need to stick to same controllers and routes for SecondBundle.

Then I created SecondBundle that should inherit FirstBundle, but I don't really know how to tell routing to stick in SecondBundle for www.site2.com.

If I add the getParent method in SecondBundle.php to force inheritance :

```
class MyAppSecondBundle extends Bundle
{
  public function getParent()
  {
    return 'FirstBundle';
  }
}
```

My site1 always display inherited stuff... I don't know how to force only site2 to stick to SecondBundle without site1 being affected.

Answer (score 1):

As of symfony 2.2 you can match routes based on hostnames:

```
mobile_homepage:
    path:     /
    host:     m.example.com
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Main:mobileHomepage }

homepage:
    path:     /
    defaults: { _controller: AcmeDemoBundle:Main:homepage }
```

See [the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/routing/hostname_pattern.html)

Comment: I forgot to say I need to keep same routing without changing controllers... It is not a good solution for me to duplicate controller or routes because there is too many of them...